# Can you override Date.Now or Date.Today for debugging purposes in an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date

We have a very massive system where reports are run off dates from specific days through to today's date using various definitions of "GenerateSalesReport(DateStart, Date.Now)".

For debugging purposes, I want to simulate reports that occurred in the past so I need to change the object "Date.Now" to a specific date from the past on my development environment. Is it possible to override `date.Now`?

Comment: Is it possible to rewind System date/time?

Comment: Can't you just change the time/date on the server?

Comment: Maybe if you try and change your system time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is one of the failings of `DateTime.Now` and related functions.

You should be passing in a `DateTime` to any function that relies on it. Any place you use `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` (and such) is a place where you should be passing in the date.

This allows you to test for different `DateTime` values, will make your code more testable and remove the temporal dependency.

Answer (score 4):

A good solution is to abstract away external dependencies to be able to be able to stub them during test. To virtualize time I often use something like this:

```
public interface ITimeService {

  DateTime Now { get; }

  void Sleep(TimeSpan timeSpan);

}
```

In your case you don't need the `Sleep` part since you only depend on the current time, and of course you need to modify your code to use an externally supplied `ITimeService` when the current time is required.

Normally you would use this implementation:

```
public class TimeService : ITimeService {

  public DateTime Now { get { return DateTime.Now; }

  public void Sleep(TimeSpan timeSpan) { Thread.Sleep(timeSpan); }

}
```

For testing purposes you can instead use this stub:

```
public class TimeServiceStub : ITimeService {

  public TimeServiceStub(DateTime startTime) { Now = startTime; }

  public DateTime Now { get; private set; }

  public void Sleep(TimeSpan timeSpan) { Now += timeSpan; }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if this were possible, you'd probably be better off changing the system time. Otherwise you've created a whole new test case (where your system is running under a different time than every other process on the system). Who knows what kind of problems you could run into.